# My app has been approved for permissions, but cannot use the approved permissions when logging in

Tags: facebook, permissions

I am making a website with the function of linking to facebook and creating posts on fanpage. I have created facebook app and the permissions have been approved [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpDcT.png). All works fine when I login with the admin account of the app but when I login with another user account there is no dialog asking for permission. This resulted in the app not getting the token with the permissions I needed to post.
Hope you can help me.

This is connect function

```
public function connect($user)
{
    $urlAuth = Socialite::driver('facebook')
                ->scopes([
                    'pages_manage_metadata',
                    'instagram_basic', 'instagram_content_publish', 
                    'pages_manage_posts', 'pages_read_engagement',
                    'pages_show_list'
                ])
                ->with(['state' => $user->id])
                ->stateless()->redirect()
                ->getTargetUrl();
    
    return $urlAuth;
}
```

This is callback function

```
public function callback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

    $token = $user->token;

    if($token){
        $facebook = new FacebookPublisher($token);
        $account = $facebook->getAccount()->data ?? [];
        $userID = request()->state;

        if(count($account) == 1){
            $account = $account[0];
            
            $userInit = User::findOrFail($userID);

            $this->savePageInfo($token, $userInit, $account);

            $url = config("api.client.connect_account_url");

        }else{
            $this->saveAccessToken($token, $pageToken = "", $userID);
            $url = config("api.client.connect_page_url");
        }

        return redirect($url);
    }

    return $this->error(trans('Connect fail!'), [], 404);
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Show us your login code then.

Comment: @CBroe Please see the code below. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe Please help me check again. Thanks

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong with that. When the login dialog shows, does the `scope` parameter in the URL include all those permissions you specified? (For the account, where it is not working.)

Comment: @CBroe This is the URL when I login. "https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=646503216792502&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.meo.ethan-tech.asia%2Fapi%2Fpublisher%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Cpages_manage_metadata%2Cinstagram_basic%2Cinstagram_content_publish%2Cpages_manage_posts%2Cpages_read_engagement%2Cpages_show_list&response_type=code&state=52"

Comment: @CBroe Excute me, do you have any other ideas about this incident?

Comment: URL looks okay to me, but it doesn't ask me for any of these advanced permissions either when I try to login. Sorry, can't tell what might be wrong here. Maybe it's a current Facebook bug.